# Retrieve users Likes from facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, extract

I'm new at this, and I have a general question -

In generally, if i have my friend E-mails address, is it possible to extract a list of the pages he likes?
when i enter to his profile I can see this list.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Of course that´s not possible at all, and it would be a serious privacy issue. You can only get the list of Pages from users who authorized your Apps, with the [`/me/likes`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/user/likes) endpoint.